Creating a bootable usb drive in linux not from a iso but from the running drives (so from / and /boot)
I found this:
https://averagelinuxuser.com/make-a-bootable-usb-drive-in-linux/
and it creates a bootable usb drive from a ISO image.  What I need is to create a bootable USB drive from the linux machine I am currently on, there is no ISO for it.   DD seems to only work from an iso (or a device but my / and /boot are both over two different raid arrays).
I thought somehow create the partitions on the USB drive for / and /boot and then rsync each respectively?   Just not sure how to go about that.
